# Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid. - new Uri("​https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/msix/app-installer/update-settings")

Tags: c#, uri

I have a very simple 2 lines console app (.net 6) and whilst creating a `Uri`,

```cs
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
var uri = new Uri("​https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/msix/app-installer/update-settings");
```

I am getting the following exception. I must be doing something really silly here, but can't figure it out. I have tried simple urls too with the same result.

```
System.UriFormatException
  HResult=0x80131537
  Message=Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.
  Source=System.Private.Uri
  StackTrace:
   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind, UriCreationOptions& creationOptions)
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\user\source\repos2\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an additional symbol in string (it is not displayed here on SO). This is after copying from your question:

[image]

Delete this symbol before `https` and it will work.

Comment: This is a [zero width space](https://unicode-explorer.com/c/200B). You can get one [here](https://zerowidthspace.me/).